# Anyone know what is being used to get this effect? Photoshop or something different?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

Anyone have any idea how this is made? [image]

Answer (score 3):

It's in Photoshop, a gray colored letter B has been written as a new layer. The used font is some fraktur type, maybe Wittenberger Fraktur Bold. I haven't such, so I use only something ordinary.

[image]

You must have big enough image in pixels to retain the sharpness through the process. I have 1000 pixels high B.

I made a rasterized copy of it for latter use and added to the text B layer style "Bevel & Emboss" for metallic effect. The adjustments are critical, but you can tweak them later.

[image]

The colorizing is made with adjustment layer "Gradient Map". My gradient is quite random. It interacts strongly with the embossing, so both must be adjusted for the wanted effect. I skip further adjustments.

[image]

Check for ex. this tutorial for further info of gradient maps:

https://digital-photography-school.com/working-with-gradient-maps-photoshop-creative/

The rasterized copy of B is brought to top and got filtering "Add noise":

[image]

The noised  B affects to underlying image with blending mode Overlay. It surely pays off to try other blending modes, too and adjust the opacity.

[image]

The overlay makes the image darker. It can be compensated with Curves adjustment layer:

[image]

The apparent contrast gets a boost if the image is placed on black background. To prevent the adjustment layer affect to the background the former layers are grouped. The same cannot be made by switching the adjustment layers to affect only the next layer, because there's a layer style which is itself a complex structure.

The black end has been lifted a little in the curves layer to make difference to the background.

[image]