# anyone have an idea how to make shapes like this in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image: hope you can help me figure out how to make shapes like this]

Sorry I just started out learning everything. thank you guys

Comment: Please don't post your question twice, your last question was closed because it lacked information and effort, you can edit it and try to get it reopened. Also, please [contact](/contact) stack exchange to get your two accounts merged together.

Comment: I just read the question and wanted to know how to make shapes like this. didn't know using a picture twice with a different questions was inappropriate here. thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: I thought I had seen that before... — @whythat__, nobody said you can't use the same image, but I definitely fail to see how this is a different question. What are these shapes you're talking about? If the answer in that other question didn't tell you enough... I don't know what you're asking. The only thing left out of that answer was how to make the letter... Is that what you don't know how to do? Check out this [tutorial](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/adding-text-shapes-basics.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some guesses about the coloring are given as an answer to the duplicate candidate question

[Anyone know what is being used to get this effect? Photoshop or something different?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/118026/anyone-know-what-is-being-used-to-get-this-effect-photoshop-or-something-differ).

But the geometric shape is text. I bet it's a B and the used font is Wittenberger Fraktur Bold. It's not free.

[image]

Someone has drawn the glyphs for the font about 500 years ago. You can in theory do it, too. Take the pen tool in PS and draw. Illustrator has better tools for vector drawings, but creating a typeface from scratch is anything but a trivial task, no matter how good drawing tools you have.

If you succeed to create an interesting and consistent set of glyphs, you obviously want to transform them to a computer font. That's possible in font editing software.The needed effort after creating the glyphs, is still substantial if you want to define typographic details properly, not by using defaults.